# Updating entity object in another window

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework

I have one problem in using Entity Framework.
My application base on silverlight and I have 2 window in it.

1. ChooseEmployeeWindow.cs
2. ChangeEmployeeWindow.cs

all of my windows have a instance of **entityModelClass**

My users in first window choose one employee and send selected employee to constructor of second window for changing properties.
When I want to save change with my instance of entityModelClass , it not saved to database.

How can I solve this problem.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A Silverlight application runs on a client which can't directly connect to a database. You need some sort of interface, a WCF service for example, through which a client can send changes to a server, and then write the changes to the database from there.

Comment: I use DataService in my application . my problem is updating an entity object in other form.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. It's hard to answer that without understanding how ChangeEmployeeWindow works. Perhaps if you include some code your problem might be easier to solve.